# Deleting columns that contain values from another list within the same spreadsheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with 40,000 products in and I want to remove a list of 800.

Each of the items have a unique ID for example the ID numbers range from 2000 - 30000

How do I do a quick find on each individual unique ID and then remove it from my product table?

Column A is my list of 40,000 and column X has my list of 800 which I need to delete from Column A...

Answer (score 0):

In a column next to your big table, text for exact match of value in A as compared to the whole range of values in X:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, X:X, 0))
```

and apply auto-filter to TRUE - these are the rows that you can delete (after double checking).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added this forumla to column Z, but every item comes back as FALSE which would be in correct as I know the items are within the 40,000. What am I doing wrong. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In a column next to your big table, test for exact match of value in A as compared to the whole range of values in X:

```
   =IF(COUNTIF(X:X,A1)>0,"Delete","Don’t Delete")
```

and apply auto-filter to "Delete"- these are the rows that you may want to delete.